# In Dojo, is it possible to change the parent of the DateTextBox dropdown?

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I have a Dojo Form in which I have a couple of DateTextBox fields. Here is the issue, when I click the button to open the dropdown to select a date, that dialog is created under the `<body>` tag and not under the `<div>` I'm in. This means that if I mouse over to it, the `mouse.leave` event I have on that `<div>` gets triggered. It is possible to anchor this dialog under my div?

Comment: Can you put an example on the code?? are you creating it programmatically or Declaratively?

Comment: I had kinda same issue, but was using popup and tooltipDialog (same what the datetextbox is using). I sticked the popup.open not around the domNode but with x and y axes evt.clientX - 5 and evt.clientY - 5

Comment: @tik27 I will try to make a fiddle for it. I'm creating it declarative. But adding the events programatically.